# UE4 Blueprint Multiplayer Spawning Issue

Tags: multiplayer, unreal-4, blueprints, online, spawning

I'm attempting to copy/modify the MultiplayerShootout project's multiplayer functionality for my own project. I'm running into issues when Player 2 joins a running session though. Finding it very hard to debug multiplayer stuff because you have to run it in standalone and toggling breakpoints doesn't seem to be illustrating any issues.

Here's the issue:
[https://youtu.be/270p4YS36Pw](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=270p4YS36Pw)

The first player to search for a game hosts a game, then the OnPostLogin in the GameMode fires and calls the ClientPostLogin event in the PlayerController, then the PlayerController calls the RespawnPlayer event inside the GameMode which spawns and possesses the character. The second player finds a session and joins it, but the server is not spawning a character for them on the other PlayerStart.

The logic is very much similar to the MultiplayerShootout, but I have modified it in the following ways:

The 1v1 button searches for sessions, and if it can't find any it will automatically host a session.

The ClientPostLogin event on the PlayerController and the RespawnPlayer event on the GameMode accepts a Selected Character (Actor class) variable. This is so I can get the player to select their character before they matchmake and pass it through to the PlayerController and then GameMode for spawning purposes. Would really appreciate some help on this, been stuck on it for a while.

Here's some of the blueprint scripting to make sense of it:

[image: OnPostLogin event in the GameMode]

OnPostLogin event in the GameMode

[image: ClientPostLogin in the PlayerController]
ClientPostLogin in the PlayerController

[image: RespawnPlayer event in the GameMode]
RespawnPlayer event in the GameMode

[image: 1v1 button released event in the PlayScreen Widget]
1v1 button released event in the PlayScreen Widget

[image: HostGame event in the GameInstance]
HostGame event in the GameInstance

[image: JoinGame event in the GameInstance]
JoinGame event in the GameInstance

Edit: I'm using UEngine version 4.24.3

Comment: You don't need to write "FIXED" into the title of your question. When you solved your problem yourself, then just accept your answer and the question will appear as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the RespawnPlayerEvent into the PlayerController fixed this. I think it had to do with the inability for the second client who joins (who is not the server host) to call a function in the GameMode (which only exists on the server).

[image: RespawnPlayerEvent inside PlayerController]
[image: ClientPostLogin inside PlayerController]

To sum it up:

- The player selects a character and stores the actor class in a
  variable inside the GameInstance (this is because the GameInstance
  does not lose information upon traveling to different maps).
- When a player joins/hosts a server the OnPostLogin event fires, passing the PlayerController and firing the ClientPostLogin event inside the PlayerController.
- The PlayerController then gets the Selected Character variable from the GameInstance and passes it on to the RespawnPlayerEvent which is also inside the PlayerController.